# Принудительное скачивание mp4 файлов

Tags: apache, .htaccess

При нажатии на ссылку с файлом MP4 он открывается в браузере. 
Что можно прописать в .htaccess, чтобы mp4 файлы скачивались, а не открывались?

Это не помогло:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|jpe?g|png)$"> 
ForceType none 
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в .htaccess

    AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
    AddType application/octet-stream .jpg
    AddType application/octet-stream .png

Comment: Не помогло.=)

Answer (score 1):

Должно сработать. Прописываем в .htaccess

```
<files *.mp4>
    forceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</files>
```

Comment: Нет. 
Не помогло.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, проверьте, установлен ли на сервере `mod_headers`.

Comment: Включен модуль.